# How should I search items in a nested HashMap with inner key?

Tags: java, search, nested, hashmap, treemap

I have a nested HashMap `HashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, Item>>`, and now I know the inner key `Id(Integer)` in TreeMap but don't have the key `String` in HashMap. Could I use some build-in methods or something else without iterating the HashMap to get what I want?

Previously, if I know the key `String`, I can use `HashMap.get(String key)`to get the item, and then use `TreeMap.get(Integer inner_key)`, but I don't know what to do now if I don't have the outside key. Is it iterating the HashMap the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... Could I use some build-in methods or something else without iterating the HashMap to get what I want? ..."*

Unfortunately not.  Although, an iteration is only a few lines.

```java
String key(int i, HashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, Item>> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, TreeMap<Integer, Item>> e : map.entrySet())
        if (e.getValue().containsKey(i)) return e.getKey();
    return null;
}
```

Alternately, use a *stream*.

```java
String key(int i, HashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, Item>> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .filter(x -> x.getValue().containsKey(i))
              .findFirst()
              .get().getKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's all what I want, wish u a good day:)